# SQL exception, Generated keys not requested

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, sqlexception

This exception is occur in mentioned section of my code:

```
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

String query = "Insert into ...";
try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query, java.sql.Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.executeUpdate(query);
        rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();  // Exception is here
    }

    while (resultset.next()) {
        id = String.valueOf(resultset.getInt(1));
    }
```

Exception:

> Generated keys not requested. You need to specify Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to Statement.executeUpdate() or Connection.prepareStatement()

My purpose is inserting a new record and save the first field (`id`) (that is `auto_increment`) to variable `id`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use mysql

Comment: The second example does not contain the `java.sql.Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` parameter for the `prepareStatement()` call

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name See Update2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, my query is an `Insert` statement, Not an `UPDATE`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My purpose is inserting a new record and the record first field (`id`) is `auto_increment` .

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So why you tried to tell me using `executeQuery()` ?

Comment: Ah!!! Sorry for that. Of course it should be `executeUpdate()`

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong `execute` method. Instead of the one taking a `String`, you should use one without a parameter. And as Chris Joslin mentioned, for `INSERT` it is better to use `executeUpdate`.

Technically a correct JDBC driver should throw an `SQLException` immediately when calling `execute(String)` or one of its siblings on a `PreparedStatement`, but some drivers ignore this rule.

Answer (score 2):

Try ps.executeUpdate() instead of ps.execute().

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
String query = "Insert into Books(Name,ISBN,Status,Date)" +
    "values( '" + name + "','" + isbn + "','" + status+ "','" + date + "' ) ";
try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query,java.sql.Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();   // Exception is here
}
```

It looks like in your first example, you do a prepare correctly, but then call the executeUpdate with the Query String again instead of just the ps.executeUpdate().

```
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query, java.sql.Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ps.executeUpdate(query);
```